# How to create a shell script to launch 3 terminals and execute a set of commands in each?

Tags: shell, terminal, xterm, gnome-terminal

Currently, I open 3 terminals ('openocd session','telnet session' & 'gdb session') and execute 'a set of commands' in each terminal every time I flash my image on target.

Is is possible to put this in one shell script file and run at once? (Commands on each terminal are NOT dependent on others; except that the terminals should be opened in the order mentioned above)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which terminal are you using?

A terminal like `xterm` can start a program instead of a shell. Simply run

```
xterm -e 'command args ...'
```

I use this to start my email client:

```
xterm -e mutt
```

If you use a different terminal, consult its manual page. I'm pretty sure there's an equivalent for `-e`.

Comment: I am using GNOME terminal emulator in Ubuntu.

Comment: @sniper Same option: e.g. `gnome-terminal -e top`

Comment: Okay I did this and I added the -hold option so that the window doesn't close, but now I can't type commands in the window, it is just frozen.