# How to write a shell script to open four terminals and execute a command in each?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, xterm

So I'm trying to create a shell script to do open up four terminal windows (konsoles preferably) and run a command in each and then keep each of those terminals open so I can continue to execute commands in them if desired.

I tried following the instructions listed here:

1. [How to create a shell script to launch 3 terminals and execute a set of commands in each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794967/how-to-create-a-shell-script-to-launch-3-terminals-and-execute-a-set-of-commands)

and

2. [How can I make a script that opens terminal windows and executes
   commands in them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the)

and after trying those details the best I have is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# some older test, doesn't work and complains and I get this message on command line: "QApplication::qAppName: Please instantiate the QApplication object first"
# I also can't enter text after command executes
#echo "Hello World!"
#exec konsole --noclose -e cat ~/.aliases 

# opens terminal but then I can't control terminal afterwards    
xterm -hold -e "echo Hello My World"

# didn't do anything
#exit 0

# didn't do anything except make me type exit an extra time where I executed my shell script
#$SHELL
```

EDIT:
Using Roberto's answer I get four terminals like this, but I can't enter additional commands, notice how there is no prompt like "mycomputername> ":

[image]

EDIT 2:

I found an even better way to do what I want. The script below will execute the commands listed in the cmds array in a separate terminal. So echo 'hello1' will run in one terminal, and echo 'hello2' will run in another terminal. This will continue for as many commands listed in the cmds array

```
!/bin/bash
# Shell script to open terminals
# and execute a separate command in each

# Commands to run (one per terminal)
cmds=('echo 'hello1'', 'echo 'hello2'')

# Loop through commands, open terminal, execute command
for i in "${cmds[@]}"
do
    xterm -e "$i && /bin/tcsh" &
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a "for" loop, and a "&" to run xterm in background:

---

```
#!/bin/bash

# some older test, doesn't work and complains and I get this message on command line: "QApplication::qAppName: Please instantiate the QApplication object first"
# I also can't enter text after command executes
#echo "Hello World!"
#exec konsole --noclose -e cat ~/.aliases

for i in 1 2 3 4
do
# opens terminal but then I can't control terminal afterwards
xterm -hold -e "echo Hello My World" &
done

# didn't do anything
#exit 0

# didn't do anything except make me type exit an extra time where I executed my shell script
#$SHELL
```

Comment: So that opens up the four terminals. I want each terminal to be executing a different command (e.g. helloworld1, helloworld2,..4), the main problem here is that I can't control any of the terminals. They each open up, display "Hello World", but there is no command line where I can enter additional text in these new windows. I posted a picture in the question so you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Then your command must be "/bin/bash" instead of "echo Hello My World"

Comment: Or maybe "echo Hello My World && /bin/bash". This will execute first commando (echo), and will execute shell if first command ends correctly.

Comment: okay I did the command in your second comment, but when I type exit the terminals don't close

Comment: Avoid "-hold" on "xterm" command: "xterm -e "echo Hello World && /bin/bash" &"

Answer (score 4):

## Konsole

### multiple windows

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
konsole --noclose -e echo Hello terminal 1! &
konsole --noclose -e echo Hello terminal 2! &
konsole --noclose -e echo Hello terminal 3! &
konsole --noclose -e echo Hello terminal 4! &
```

### multiple tabs

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
konsole --noclose --new-tab -e echo Hello terminal 1! &
konsole --noclose --new-tab -e echo Hello terminal 2! &
konsole --noclose --new-tab -e echo Hello terminal 3! &
konsole --noclose --new-tab -e echo Hello terminal 4! &
```

Comment: `multiple windows` works in my kUbuntue v 20.04 . BTW not `multiple tabs` in my simple /bin/bash terminal

Answer (score 1):

On a Linux Mint ***mate*** distribution, this will run `<commands>` in 3 separated terminal windows:

```
$ cat START.sh

mate-terminal --execute bash -c "<command1>" 
mate-terminal --execute bash -c "<command2>" 
mate-terminal --execute bash -c "<command3>"
```

Killing *START.sh* won't terminate children `<commands>`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be quite easily:

```
#!usr/bin/env bash
echo "Enter the value of n:"
read n
for ((i = 0; i < n; i++ ))
do 
   xterm -hold -e <enter command> &
   # In my case, I used : 
   # xterm -hold -e sar -P $i 2 5 &
done
```

And that's pretty much it! Have a good day :)

**Note** : For those who are newbies, we save this with a file name **'.sh'**. Also, please note that this will execute n different commands on n different terminals. If you want, you can execute the same command on every terminal, just remove $i from the  in do .... done part ;)